# CI+ Communication in the HbbTV platform

Tags: javascript, smart-tv, hbbtv, ciplus

Does anyone know how to communicate with CI+ CAM module via HbbTV 1.2.1/1.1.1?

We have created these objects

```
<object type="application/oipfDrmAgent" id="oipfDrmAgent"></object>
<object type="application/oipfGatewayInfo" id="gatewayinfo"></object>
```

Before sending data to CI+ module, we need to know CI+ status and  Samsung TV 2014 has a true value of `isCSPGCIPlusSupported`. Others TV like a LG, Panasonic, VESTEL have a false value.

... and now we called

```
drmagent = document.getElementById('oipfDrmAgent');
drmagent.onDRMSystemMessage = this.onDRMMessage; 
drmagent.onDRMMessageResult = this.onDRMRetrieve;
ret = drmagent.sendDRMMessage("application/vnd.oipf.cspg-hexbinary", '0x0108113101190000' ,'urn:dvb:casystemid:3478');
```

And we have retrieved message number [], resultMsg has null object and resultCode has a value 2.

```
onDRMRetrieve: function(msgID, resultMsg, resultCode){
  var drminfo = document.getElementById('drminfo');
 drminfo.innerHTML += '<br />DRM retrieve message' + msgID + ' ' + resultMsg + ' ' + resultCode;
},
```

Note: ETSI TS 102 796 V1.1.1 (2010-06) has defined sending messages via `sendContentPurchaseMessage()`, but this function is not defined.

We have three questions:
1) How to make a message string passed via `sendDRMMessage` like a '0x0108113101190000'?
2) We need to know how to get the CSSN number from CI+ card.
3) Are there any security problems related?

Regards,
STeN